# Grub 'incompatible license' error

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, keyboard, grub2

The other day, I was using a laptop for general desktop use when its keyboard began to act up. Most of the keys on the keyboard's right side stopped working entirely and key combinations such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> made characters appear that should not have appeared. The backspace key exhibited the strangest behavior; it was somehow able to cause the deletion characters in the shell prompt.

I was unable to reboot the computer cleanly so I did a hard shutdown. When I turned the computer on again, I received this message from Grub:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

incompatible license
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

I pressed the any key and Grub responded with

```
Operating System Not Found.
```

Pressing another key causes the first message to appear again. Pressing another key after that causes the second message to appear... and so on.

If I leave the laptop on for a few minutes, its fan speeds up significantly as if the laptop is running a CPU-intensive program.

I took the hard drive out of the laptop, mounted it on a server, and looked around. I saw nothing strange in `/boot`.

The laptop is running Arch Linux. The drive is partitioned with GPT. The laptop works fine with a hard drive from another machine. And other machines do not work with the laptop's hard drive.

I am not certain that the keyboard issues are directly related to the Grub issues.

What could be causing the problems that I am having? Or, what should I do to find out or narrow down the list of potential causes?

Just in case it's relevant, here *(removed)* is a tarball with `/boot` and `/etc/grub.d` and here is my Grub configuration:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux PARA kernel' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-PARA kernel-true-d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux PARA kernel ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-PARA root=UUID=d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-PARA.img
}
menuentry 'Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux core repo kernel' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-core repo kernel-true-d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux core repo kernel ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
menuentry 'Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux core repo kernel (Fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-core repo kernel-fallback-d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux core repo kernel ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=d44f2a2f-c369-456b-81f1-efa13f9caae2 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" --class memtest86 --class gnu --class tool {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd1,gpt1'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b4fbf4f8-303c-49bd-a52f-6049e1623a26
  fi
  linux16 ($root)/boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

---

**Update**

After installing LILO last night, the computer booted just fine at least once. When I booted the computer this morning, I was faced with a kernel panic:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: junk in compressed archive
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.8.7-1-ARCH #1
Call Trace:
...
```

[Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/58435130@N08/8695859408/in/photostream) is a picture of the kernel panic.

**Update 2**

I reinstalled LILO and no longer receive the kernel panic on boot.

Comment: This may well be a hardware problem. First thing to try: yank out the battery and the power plug, wait a few seconds, try again. Second thing: do a memory test, let it stew for a few hours.

Comment: I've tried removing all sources of power. I'll run a memory test right now.

Comment: I also tried reinstalling Grub with no effect. I'm going to install syslinux.

Comment: I ended up installing LILO, which does not seem to be having any problems. The memory test did not find any errors and I don't see any keyboard issues (terminal or shell issues, perhaps?) Is it possible that the hard shutdown caused the Grub issues?

Comment: Now I am receiving a kernel panic on boot (see update to question.)

Comment: I reinstalled LILO and I no longer receive the kernel panic on boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update2:***

Forgot you posted the tar ball. Too bad. Anyhow, did a test on your `.mod` files
by using the below code and:

```
./grum_lic_test32 evan_teitelman/boot/grub/i386-pc/*.mod
```

which yielded the following error:

```
...
bufio.mod                 License: LICENSE=GPLv3+            OK
cacheinfo.mod             License: LICENSE=NONE_FOUND        ERR
cat.mod                   License: LICENSE=GPLv3+            OK
chain.mod                 License: LICENSE=GPLv3+            OK
...
```

but that file is identical with the one from Archlinux download, so it should
not be an issue. In other words, was not the cause.

Also, first now, notice you have installed LILO, – and guess by that the case
is closed. If not there is always the question about GPT and BIOS + other issues. Did you install it the first time? Can be that there was some tweak
involved on first install that reinstall of GRUB did not fix.

---

***Update1:*** OK. Fixed. Should work for both 32 and 64-bit `ELF`'s.

---

When `GRUB` get to the phase of loading modules it check for license embedded
in `ELF` file for each module. If non valid is found the module is ignored –
and that specific error is printed. Could be one or more modules are corrupted.

If it is an essential module everything would go bad. Say e.g `part_gpt.mod` 
or `part_msdos.mod`.

Accepted licenses are `GPLv2+`, `GPLv3` and `GPLv3+`.

It could of course be other reasons; but one of many could be corrupted module file(s).

It seems like the modules are valid `ELF` files as they are validated as such
before the license test. As in: if `ELF` test fail license test is not executed.

Had another issue with modules where I needed to check for various, have 
extracted parts of that code and made it into a quick license tester. You could
test each `*.mod` file in `/boot/grub/*` to see which one(s) are corrupt.

This code does not validate `ELF` or anything else. Only try to locate license
string and check that. Further it is only tested under i386/32-bit. The original
code where it is extracted from worked for x86-64 as well – but here a lot is stripped and hacked so I'm not sure of the result. If it doesn't work under 64-bit it should most likely only print `License: LICENSE=NONE_FOUND`.

*(As noted in edit above I have now tested for 32 and 64-bit, Intel.)*

As a separate test then would be to do something like:

```
xxd file.mod | grep -C1 LIC
```

---

Not the most beautiful code – but as a quick and dirty check.

*(As in; you could try.*)

Compile instructions e.g.:

```
gcc -o grub_lic_test32 source.c         # 32-bit variant
gcc -o grub_lic_test64 source.c -DELF64 # 64-bit variant
```

Run:

```
./grub_lic_test32 /path/to/mods/*.mod
```

Prints each file and license, eg:

```
./grub_lic_test32 tar.mod gettext.mod pxe.mod
tar.mod                   License: LICENSE=GPLv1+            BAD
gettext.mod               License: LICENSE=GPLv3+            OK
pxe.mod                   License: LICENSE=GPLv3+            OK
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifdef ELF64
struct ELF_hdr
{
    unsigned char dummy0[16];
    uint32_t dummy1[6];
    uint64_t sh_off;
    uint16_t dummy2[5];
    uint16_t sh_entsize;
    uint16_t sh_num;
    uint16_t sh_strndx;
};
struct ELF_sect_hdr
{
    uint32_t sh_name;
    uint32_t dummy0[5];
    uint64_t sh_offset;
};
#else
struct ELF_hdr
{
    unsigned char dummy0[16];
    uint32_t dummy1[4];
    uint32_t sh_off;
    uint16_t dummy2[5];
    uint16_t sh_entsize;
    uint16_t sh_num;
    uint16_t sh_strndx;
};
struct ELF_sect_hdr
{
    uint32_t sh_name;
    uint32_t dummy[3];
    uint32_t sh_offset;
};
#endif

enum {
    ERR_FILE_OPEN = 1,
    ERR_FILE_READ,
    ERR_MEM,
    ERR_BAD_LICENSE,
    ERR_ELF_SECT_CORE_BREACH
};

int file_size(FILE *fh, size_t *fs)
{
    size_t cp;

    cp = ftell(fh);
    fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END);
    *fs = ftell(fh);
    fseek(fh, cp, SEEK_SET);

    return 0;
}

static const char *valid_licenses[] = {
    "LICENSE=GPLv2+",
    "LICENSE=GPLv3",
    "LICENSE=GPLv3+",
    NULL
};

int grub_check_license(struct ELF_hdr *e)
{
    struct ELF_sect_hdr *s;
    const char *txt;
    const char *lic;
    unsigned i, j = 0;

    s = (struct ELF_sect_hdr *)
        ((char *) e + e->sh_off + e->sh_strndx * e->sh_entsize);

    txt = (char *) e + s->sh_offset;

    s = (struct ELF_sect_hdr *) ((char *) e + e->sh_off);

    for (i = 0; i < e->sh_num; ++i) {
        if (strcmp (txt + s->sh_name, ".module_license") == 0) {
            lic = (char*) e + s->sh_offset;

            if (j)
                fprintf(stdout, "%25s", "");
            fprintf(stdout, "License: %-25s ", lic);

            for (j = 0; valid_licenses[j]; ++j) {
                if (!strcmp (lic, valid_licenses[j])) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "OK\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "BAD\n");
        }
        s = (struct ELF_sect_hdr *) ((char *) s + e->sh_entsize);
    }

    if (!j)
        fprintf(stdout, "License: %-25s ERR\n", "LICENSE=NONE_FOUND");

    return ERR_BAD_LICENSE;
}

int grub_check_module(void *buf, size_t size, int verbose)
{
    struct ELF_hdr *e = buf;

    /* Make sure that every section is within the core.  */
    if (e->sh_off + e->sh_entsize * e->sh_num > size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERR: Sections outside core\n");
        if (verbose)
            fprintf(stderr,
                "  %*s: %u bytes\n"
#ifdef ELF64
                "  %*s  %u < %llu\n"
                "  %*s: %llu\n"
#else
                "  %*s  %u < %u\n"
                "  %*s: %u\n"
#endif
                "  %*s: %u\n"
                "  %*s: %u\n"
                ,
                -25, "file-size", size,
                -25, "",
                size, e->sh_off + e->sh_entsize * e->sh_num,
                -25, "sector header offset", e->sh_off,
                -25, "sector header entry size", e->sh_entsize,
                -25, "sector header num", e->sh_num
            );
        return ERR_ELF_SECT_CORE_BREACH;
    }

    return grub_check_license(e);
}

int grub_check_module_file(const char *fn, int verbose)
{
    FILE *fh;
    void *buf;
    size_t fs;
    int eno;
    char *base_fn;

    if (!(base_fn = strrchr(fn, '/')))
        base_fn = (char*)fn;
    else
        ++base_fn;

    fprintf(stderr, "%-25s ", base_fn);

    if (!(fh = fopen(fn, "rb"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERR: Unable to open `%s'\n", fn);
        perror("fopen");
        return ERR_FILE_OPEN;
    }
    file_size(fh, &fs);
    if (!(buf = malloc(fs))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERR: Memory.\n");
        fclose(fh);
        return ERR_MEM;
    }
    if (fread(buf, 1, fs, fh) != fs) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERR: Reading `%s'\n", fn);
        perror("fread");
        free(buf);
        fclose(fh);
        return ERR_FILE_READ;
    }
    fclose(fh);

    eno = grub_check_module(buf, fs, verbose);
    free(buf);

    return eno;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    int eno = 0;
    int verbose = 0;

    if (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'v') {
        verbose = 1;
        ++i;
    }

    if (argc - i < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-v] <FILE>[, FILE[, ...]]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }


    for (; i < argc; ++i) {
        eno |= grub_check_module_file(argv[i], verbose);
        if (eno == ERR_MEM)
            return eno;
    }

    return eno;
}
```

Comment: I don't recall tweaking my Grub install. Thank you for spending the time to put together that module testing code.

Comment: Your answer didn't directly answer my original question so I modified my question a bit. Once this question is eligible for bounty, I will send another 50 reputation your way to repay you for your time. Thanks again.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman: Thanks a lot, but no need for bounty points. Keep your hard earned points for a rainy day ;). When it comes to GPT [this read](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread over on ubuntugeek.com titled: [Boot-Repair – Simple tool to repair frequent boot problems](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-repair-simple-tool-to-repair-frequent-boot-problems.html). This tool may be able to help repair what's wrong with your HDD. Looking at the list of features this seems like the easiest way to try and repair your boot partition without getting your hands too dirty.

[image: ss of Boot-Repair]

Comment: After seeing the image you posted, I reinstalled Grub. Unfortunately, the reinstall seemed to have no effect.